# Specifying C(++) dependencies for python packages for use in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, gcc, linker, pip, aws-lambda

I have a serverless service that I want to be able to use the `sasl` pypi package from in AWS Lambda. Unfortunately, the AWS Lambda environment doesn't seem to have the newest versions of libstdc++.so, which means that when our build server zips up the `pip install`'d sasl package and we invoke the lambda, there are the expected errors:

```
Unable to import module 'handler': /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /var/task/sasl/saslwrapper.so)
```

My question is: How to get around this? 
Is there a way to build these on an Amazon Linux instance against updated libstdc++.so.6 so that it can be bundled in with the libs? Would setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to `.` and including the newest version of libstdc++.so.6 work? Are there best practices around this anywhere?

Comment: What is "C(++)"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit c or c++

Comment: C does not use libstdc++.so.6. Please focus on _one_ language at a time. C and C++ are different. Separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use docker with `amazonlinux` as your base image to build all your dependencies then copy these to your zipped package to be uploaded to your actual lambda: https://medium.com/@johnnyopao/python-dependencies-and-aws-lambda-18acbdebca20

Or you can do the equivalent on a remote EC2 (build) instance: http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html

Last option, use AWS Cloud 9 as your IDE, as suggested by: https://markn.ca/2018/02/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: Is there a way to find which shared library object files (.so)  I should copy other than repeatedly running and collective errors?

Comment: Since my answer, AWS has released new ways of packaging Lambdas: 
- Layers in Nov. 2019 (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/)
- Docker images directly in Dec. 2020 (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)

I'd suggest using the latter (cf the official doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html). And deploying via either Serverless (https://www.serverless.com/) or AWS SAM (https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) to facilitate configuration around Lambda

Comment: And here's a thorough walk-through of this new approach: https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/packaging-aws-lambda-functions-as-container-images

Answer (score 2):

You can add simply the gcc-c++ binaries needed with this custom gcc version for lambda :
https://github.com/lambci/gcc-lambda-layer

Or as Bluu answers compile your own image.

Edit : new solution : because its sometimes can be annoying to package layers especially with C++ packages ( numpy pands scrapy ect...), I made a lambda to create my layers propely and fast :
https://github.com/vincentventalon/serverless_layer_generator

Answer (score -3):

[Here's your problem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html):

> AWS Lambda is an ideal compute platform for many application scenarios, provided that you can write your application code in languages supported by AWS Lambda (that is, Node.js, Java, C# and Python)

You're doing something you shouldn't.

You might be able to hack it (I've had success in the past with redistributing *libstdc++* and *libgcc_s* from my build machine, plonking them somewhere along with my executable and making sure they're are preferred at runtime using `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'`) but you'll basically be on your own.

C++ isn't really designed to be deployed to a platform other than the one on which it was built, so unless Amazon provide a "AWS Lambda" environment to build things in, you'll be stuck with such hacks.

Comment: Well to be fair, all of my code is Python2.7 -- some libraries in a number of languages are or depend on C and C++ code/libs, and Python is no exception here. Obviously if need be, I can put it on an EC2 instance and set up polling etc to get invocation but it seems like a PITA when the rest of my services are all lambda.

Comment: you could try `pip install -b python_pkg_w_c_deps` which will download a precompiled binary if one is available ...

Comment: 'unless Amazon provide a "AWS Lambda" environment' <- this is just amazon linux afaik, in case it comes up for you later.

Comment: @ap: *shrug* I'm literally quoting the official help guide. They don't support your language.