# AWS Lambda - How to fix: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, libssl

In AWS Lambda function, I have a python file which includes some packages such as numpy, pandas, pycurl, requests,...

I provided the needed packages in a zip file, but when I run the code, i receive the following error:

***Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory***

Any idea?

Comment: can you share with us your lambda package structure ? and how you are importing in your main function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda Python libssl C Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468984/aws-lambda-python-libssl-c-library)

Comment: @WalidK I just want to see if the uploaded python packages are working... so inside the lambda handler I only: import numpy, pandas, scipy, pycurl, requests and I print('test)...

Comment: @syumaK no, this is not my case

Answer (score 1):

My case was running rust on AWS lambda and end up the error you having.

My way to get it working was including the library as a lambda layer

1. Get the libssl as file and zip it. In my case, the folder structure is lib/libssl.so.1.1. reference from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)
2. Add a Lambda Layer , Choose Custom runtime, copy down the ARN
3. Go the function and add layer with ARN.