# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libpam.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have follow this post : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-external-python-libraries-aws-lambda-using-layers-gabe-olokun/ and install ***ibm_db***  package.

After adding the aws lambda layer getting this error.

***lambda_function :***

```
import json
import ibm_db

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

***Error :***

```
Test Event Name
testdemo

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libpam.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libpam.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please kindly suggest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468984/aws-lambda-python-libssl-c-library - add the `libpam.so.0` to the layer as well.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks, but i need to upload directly in lambda function folder.

Comment: That is fine as well. Just add the file there.